# UIImage with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, uiimage, afnetworking-2

I wanted to know if it is possible to post an `UIImage` directly in the params field in AFNetworking ?
Because I saw that we can post an image if we know it's name and it's location, but in my app, the image is taken from the camera, and saved, then directly posted.

So is this possible ?

thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is this possible ?

Yes, it is possible.